# Overriding text color in React + Framer?

Tags: css, reactjs, framer-motion, framerjs

I'd like to override the text color of my Component to make it a multi-stop linear gradient. Following the code examples provided by Framer, this is what I've tried:

```
export const withCustomColor = (Component): ComponentType => {
    // This part of the code is only run once when creating the component
    return (props) => {
        // This part runs every time the component is rendered.
        return (
            <Component
                {...props}
                color="linear-gradient(70deg, #7F00FF, #00EAFF, #FFF700, #FF007B)"
            />
        )
    }
}
```

This does nothing. If I instead do the following, I get the linear gradient but as a background block, not the actual text color:

```
            <Component
                {...props}
                animate={{
                    background:
                        "linear-gradient(70deg, #7F00FF, #00EAFF, #FFF700, #FF007B)",
                }}
            />
```

But putting `color` inside the `animate` brackets does nothing.

How can I change the text color to be the linear gradient using Framer overrides?

Comment: Just guessing, but give this a try: `style={{color: "linear-gradient(70deg, #7F00FF, #00EAFF, #FFF700, #FF007B)"}}` inside `<Component ... />`. It should be noted that this would then completely override any `style=` that may be in `props`, if that happens then you'll need to get the style from props and then add `color` to it.

Comment: That isn't a valid [`color` property value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value). To make the text color a gradient, you could try adding the necessary styles from one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384751/css-text-gradient)